# How can I achieve responsive type which is 'pinned' to a specific location on a parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a graphic designer trying to teach myself web-dev by writing my own portfolio site.
The site is fairly simple, with my work laid out and divided by sub-headings/titles as the user scrolls.

I would like these subheadings/titles to be responsive to the window size and also have the the text halfway down from a parent div (which has a coloured background). I've put what I have so far in the following CodePen: https://codepen.io/s-0da/full/wvJYWNL

When viewed fullscreen my code so far is fine, but when resized the text moves about and shifts position from the vertical-centre of the parent div.

I've included this mock-up below to illustrate exactly what I'm trying to do. I want the length of the text to dictate the vertical height of the 'bar' background thing:
[Mockup of the sub-headings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN6Rk.png)

As you can see from the image, if the string of text is longer, the background element 'bar' should be vertically smaller to accomodate the text.

```css
.title{
background-color: rgb(71, 56, 56);
box-shadow: 1px 3px 7px 0px black;
border-radius: 20px;
color:white;
padding-left: 5px;
height:10vh;
text-align:start;}

.title > p{
font-size: 8vw;
text-shadow:1px 2px 10px rgb(82, 82, 82);}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="showcase-grid">
        <div class="title span">
           <p>Test Heading for Individual</p>
        </div>
        <div class="left grid-element">
        <img src="test2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="right grid-element">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
        </div>
        <div class="span grid-element">
            <img src="test.png">
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

I would really appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't copy code from their site. If you look at the edit history, you'll see that, they already had their code there and the only thing I did was move their code into a snippet??

Comment: My apologies @Sensoray! A figment of my overactive imagination apparently...

Comment: @HereticMonkey no worries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the title background height measured in screen height and the actual title measured in screen width. So both need to be measured in screen width, as does the spacing (margin) between the title and title background. A `text align:center` on the `.title` will also solve your centering issue.

```css
.title{
  background-color: rgb(71, 56, 56);
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 7px 0px black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color:white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  height:8vw;
  text-align:center;
}

.title > p{
  font-size: 8vw;
  margin:0;
  margin-top:3vw;
  display:inline-block;
  text-shadow:1px 2px 10px rgb(82, 82, 82);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="showcase-grid">
        <div class="title span">
           <p>Test Heading for Individual</p>
        </div>
        <div class="left grid-element">
        <img src="test2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="right grid-element">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
        </div>
        <div class="span grid-element">
            <img src="test.png">
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I hadn't considered the units being different causing problems. As far as my centering issue goes, I more meant the centering of the text vertically with the background div, but I think your edits have solved that. Thanks again, I appreciate it